# Select users who do not answer a survey yet

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my DB **questionnaire_self** that contains the answers of a survey.
Each item of this table has a foreign key **user_id** referred to **id** in the table **user**

What is the query to filter the users (from table user) who do not answer a survey yet, i.e., their id's are not in questionnaire_self.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very basic `Left Join`.

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN ON user.id = questionnaire_self.user_id WHERE questionnaire_self.user_id IS NULL` would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from user where id not in (select user_id from questionnaire_self)
```